# Origins, usage and connotations of the word "швабода"?

Tags: словоупотребление

Drawing an analogy with "дерьмократия" I think "швабода" is a derisive and probably vulgar way of saying "свобода" (*freedom*), but please can someone fill me in on the origins, usage, and connotations of this form.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89824/discussion-on-question-by-ruffle-origins-usage-and-connotations-of-the-word-).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a set of political-inspired meme words used extensively on the Russian Internet to mock the liberal wing (opposition) commentators:

**Швабода** (свобода) — freedom

**Швабода шлова** (свобода слова) — freedom of speech

**Швитая Омерика / Швитая Мурика** (Святая Америка) — Holy America (as opposed to Russia)

**Шанкции** (санкции) — sanctions etc.

You can draw parallels with **freedum** used on the English-speaking web in political humor context:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. So it's very politically loaded then, and indeed nasty, insofar as it derides opponents by implicitly attributing speech defects or physical infirmity to them. Another analogue in English might be "librulz" or, perhaps even closer, the form "wacist" which is used in mockery by racists when they accuse anti-racists of being too prone to complain of "wacism".

Comment: As far as origin is concerned, pronunciation variant "Швабода" predates anti-democratic rhetoric of 1990s and probably Perestroika as well.

Answer (score 3):

**Швабода** is just the way we would pronounce **свобода** in a joking manner. It resembles a child's pronunciation, or how an old man without teeth would say that.

Comment: +1, *an old man without teeth* - or a kid yet w/o teeth :) Curiously I was not even aware of such word being widely used in politically obsessed resources, so when I've first read the Q it sounded for me just like "ах ты моё шолнышко" or "ах мой жайчик" :) (And this is how it's different from "дерьмократия" which requires no special training for anyone to get its negative connotation).